# freeradius client send only accounting request, not access request

Tags: authentication, freeradius, accounting

I have freeradius 2.2.6.
Only at first connection the client send both access request and accounting request.
subsequent connections sends only accouting request!
This problem occurs ONLY with sone smartphones (all other device work)
however the client connects.

```
rad_recv: Accounting-Request packet from host 192.168.100.110 port 56137, id=246, length=165
        Acct-Session-Id = "386D43F9-0000002C"
        Acct-Status-Type = Start
        Acct-Authentic = RADIUS
        User-Name = "test"
        NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.100.110
        Vendor-29671-Attr-1 = 0x53797345646974
        NAS-Port = 0
        Called-Station-Id = "00-18-0A-7A-91-3C:Netweek"
        Calling-Station-Id = "78-4B-87-67-A9-1C"
        Framed-IP-Address = 192.168.1.33
        NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
        Connect-Info = "CONNECT 0Mbps 802.11b"
# Executing section preacct from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+group preacct {
++[preprocess] = ok
[acct_unique] WARNING: Attribute NAS-Identifier was not found in request, unique ID MAY be inconsistent
[acct_unique] Hashing 'NAS-Port = 0,,NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.100.110,Acct-Session-Id = "386D43F9-0000002C",User-Name = "test"'
[acct_unique] Acct-Unique-Session-ID = "53e7d607084daacb".
++[acct_unique] = ok
+} # group preacct = ok
# Executing section accounting from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+group accounting {
[detail]        expand: %{Packet-Src-IP-Address} -> 192.168.100.110
[detail]        expand: /usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d -> /usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/192.168.100.110/detail-20150812
[detail] /usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d expands to /usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/192.168.100.110/detail-20150812
[detail]        expand: %t -> Wed Aug 12 16:26:50 2015
++[detail] = ok
[sql]   expand: %{User-Name} -> test
[sql] sql_set_user escaped user --> 'test'
[sql]   expand: %{Acct-Delay-Time} ->
[sql]   ... expanding second conditional
[sql]   expand:            INSERT INTO radacct             (acctsessionid,    acctuniqueid,     username,              realm,            nasipaddress,     nasportid,              nasporttype,      acctstarttime,    acctstoptime,              acctsessiontime,  acctauthentic,    connectinfo_start,              connectinfo_stop, acctinputoctets,  acctoutputoctets,              calledstationid,  callingstationid, acctterminatecause,              servicetype,      framedprotocol,   framedipaddress,              acctstartdelay,   acctstopdelay,    xascendsessionsvrkey)           VALUES             ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}',              '%{SQL-User-Name}',              '%{Realm}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}', '%{NAS-Port}',              '%{NAS-Port-Type}', '%S', NULL,              '0', '%{Acct-Authentic}', '%{Connect-Info}',              '', '0', '0',              '%{Called-Station-Id}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}', '',              '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}', '%{Framed-IP-Address}',
[sql]   expand: /usr/local/var/log/radius/sqltrace.sql -> /usr/local/var/log/radius/sqltrace.sql
rlm_sql (sql): Reserving sql socket id: 27
rlm_sql_mysql: query:             INSERT INTO radacct             (acctsessionid,    acctuniqueid,     username,              realm,            nasipaddress,     nasportid,              nasporttype,      acctstarttime,    acctstoptime,              acctsessiontime,  acctauthentic,    connectinfo_start,              connectinfo_stop, acctinputoctets,  acctoutputoctets,              calledstationid,  callingstationid, acctterminatecause,              servicetype,      framedprotocol,   framedipaddress,              acctstartdelay,   acctstopdelay,    xascendsessionsvrkey)           VALUES             ('386D43F9-0000002C', '53e7d607084daacb',              'test',              '', '192.168.100.110', '0',              'Wireless-802.11', '2015-08-12 16:26:50', NULL,              '0', 'RADIUS', 'CONNECT 0Mbps 802.11b',              '', '0', '0',              '00-18-0A-7A-91-3C:Netweek', '78-4B-87-67-A9-1C', '',              '', '', '192.168.1.33',              '0', '0', '')
rlm_sql (sql): Released sql socket id: 27
++[sql] = ok
++? if (noop)
? Evaluating (noop) -> FALSE
++? if (noop) -> FALSE
[sql_log] Processing sql_log_accounting
[sql_log]       expand: %{User-Name} -> test
[sql_log]       expand: %{%{User-Name}:-DEFAULT} -> test
[sql_log] sql_set_user escaped user --> 'test'
[sql_log]       expand: INSERT INTO radacct (AcctSessionId, UserName,    NASIPAddress, FramedIPAddress, AcctStartTime, AcctStopTime,     AcctSessionTime, AcctTerminateCause) VALUES                     ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{User-Name}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}',          '%{Framed-IP-Address}', '%S', '0', '0', ''); -> INSERT INTO radacct (AcctSessionId, UserName,   NASIPAddress, FramedIPAddress, AcctStartTime, AcctStopTime,     AcctSessionTime, AcctTerminateCause) VALUES                          ('386D43F9-0000002C', 'test', '192.168.100.110',        '192.168.1.33', '2015-08-12 16:26:50', '0', '0', '');
[sql_log]       expand: /usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/sql-relay -> /usr/local/var/log/radius/radacct/sql-relay
++[sql_log] = ok
++[exec] = noop
[attr_filter.accounting_response]       expand: %{User-Name} -> test
attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 12
++[attr_filter.accounting_response] = updated
+} # group accounting = updated
Sending Accounting-Response of id 246 to 192.168.100.110 port 56137
Finished request 3.
Cleaning up request 3 ID 246 with timestamp +451
Going to the next request
Ready to process requests.
```

the problem is that such jumps controls tables radgroupreply and radgroupcheck, where I set various controls (including Simultaneous-Use = 1).

You ideee? thank you.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I use centos 6.7